# CSS nav bar div layer not displaying properly on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

My css sheet works fine with safari and mozilla but not with IE. There seems to be a specific problem with the nav bar div layer... It was built as an horizontal menu bar but it shows as a vertical menu bar on IE and pushes my flash banner aside.

Any tips on how to solve this problem?

css extract follows

```
/* Menu */

#menu {
width: 1000px;
height: 46px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
background: url(images/img04.jpg) no-repeat left top;
}
#menu ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 48px;
list-style: none;
line-height: normal;
}

#menu li {
position: relative;
float: left;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
}


#menu a {
display: block;
height: 32px;
margin-right: 3px;
padding: 14px 30px 0px 30px;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #FF9900;
border: none;
}
#menu a:hover, #menu .current_page_item a {
background: #C44203;
}

#menu .current_page_item a {
background: #C44203;
}

#menu a:hover {
background: #C44203;
text-decoration: none;
}

#menu li a{
display: inline-block;
height: 32px;
margin-right: 3px;
padding: 14px 30px 0px 30px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
line-height: 25px;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
font-weight: normal;
color: #FF9900;
border: none;
}
#menu li a:hover{
background-color: #C44203;  
}   
#menu ul ul{
display: block;
height: 60px;
margin-left:-96px;
left: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 45px;
visibility: hidden;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul{
visibility: visible;
}
```

Many, many thanks
Vivian

Comment: Show your code in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

try this link...

http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/

It sounds like `display: inline-block;` only works for IE8 and up. But the link gives you a solution and explains the benefits and fallbacks of using it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove  **`position: relative`;** from #menu li. 
It will work in IE.

Comment: that messed up the nav bar formatting and threw the subitems to the top of the bar instead of showing them right underneath the parent item... But thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

to `visibility: visible;` into `display:block;`

and `visibility:hidden;` into `Display:none;`

as like this

```
#menu ul ul{
display:none;
}

#menu ul li:hover ul{
display:block;
}
```